# how to post on friends wall using graph api in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

HI I want to post on my friends Facebook wall. I am using FbGraph gem to find my all Facebook friends & also update my own status. But I am not getting how to post on my friends wall. There are links guiding about the same

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing &

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

but I am not getting how exactly I have to use them to be able to post on my friends wall. There are similar questions but they are related to android or iPhone platform. Please guide me how can I do  the same in my rails application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 'to' parameter :

to
Profiles mentioned or targeted in this post
Requires access_token
Contains in data an array of objects, each with the name and Facebook id of the user

Just curl or use the JS SDK, pass it an object with 'to' into it.